# Rotation in 4D, number of axes required

Tags: rotations

I've noticed that rotation can be interpreted in 2 different manors. Does rotation occur about an axis, or through a pair of axes?

What I would like to know is in 4D are there 4 fundamental rotations (one about each axis) or are there 6 fundamental rotations (one about each pair of axes)?

If one of these interpretations is rotation, what is the name for the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rotation always acts on a plane. So there are 6 different rotations in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that keep two axis fixed and rotate the plane spanned by the other two. You can't rotate around an axis unless you are in $\mathbb{R}^3$. To see this consider the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, there is only one rotation of the entire plane, not two for the two axis.

Comment: Of course... The pattern is $\{1,3,?\}$. Not $\{2,3,?\}$ Thank you!

Comment: btw the number of independent rotations is $d(d-1)/2$, where $d$ is the dimensionality. It's the number of degrees of freedom of antisymmetric matrix $d\times d$